Why am I getting CORS error with 200 OK? (Cloud CDN with signed cookies)
This is Cloud CDN. I have created a bucket and a load balancer with a host and path rules like this:
Host: images.example.com Path: /* --> Bucket
I created an "A" DNS record image.example.com that points to the IP of the load balancer
The CORS policy for the bucket in my server includes:
"http://www.example.com",
"images.example.com",
"http:00.00.00" (IP of load balancer)
There is an Origin: http://www.example.com in the request header and an Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com in the response header
The resource being requested is: http://images.example.com/<bucket object path>
Request Response Error in console CORS error in console
This is the error in the console:

openseadragon.js_changed:13202 HTTP 0 attempting to load TileSource:
http://images.recordspreservation.org/Brasil/S%C3%A3o%20Paulo/Jundia%C3%AD/…hora%20do%20Desterro/%C3%93bitos%201744-1787/IMG_007_0025/IMG_007_0025.dzi
error @   openseadragon.js_changed:13202
request.onreadystatechange    @   openseadragon.js_changed:2448

Why am I getting this error and what should I check besides what I've done?
Thanks!

The status code of a respnse doesn't have anything to do with CORS (except if it's the OPTIONS request and that fails).  Please show the exact error you get (It should be logged out to the browsers console)

Please see error from console that was added to post

This is not a cors error...

Please see the image of the CORS error in the console.  I just updated the post with it.

If I remove these two properties from OpenSeaDragon ajaxWithCredentials: true, crossOriginPolicy: 'use-credentials' then I get a 403 error.

In Firefox the error is CORS Missing Allow Credentials

I don't see the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials in the response header. Is that necessary if I am using signed cookies?
